# Reorder bargraphs from high to low in facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make my bargraphs go from low to high based on my bottom graph (i.e., saltwater) in facet wrap. I was using this code to put the values in order

```
df = df |>
  mutate(Combination = fct_reorder(Combination,
                                   ifelse(!Water_Type %in% "Saltwater", 0, Total_Publications),
                                   .fun = sum
  ))
```

prior to plotting it in `ggplot` but for some reason it's not working anymore and I can't figure out why. Here is a sample of the dataframe

```
df = structure(list(Size_Groups = c("Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", 
"Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Not Reported", 
"Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
"Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
"Not Reported", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small"), Depth_Groups = c(">50m", 
"Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", 
"Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
">50m", ">50m", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
"Not Reported", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
"Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", ">50m", 
">50m", ">50m", ">50m", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
"Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Not Reported", 
"Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m"), Water_Type = c("Saltwater", 
"Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", 
"Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
"Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
"Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
"Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
"Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", 
"Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Brackish", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", 
"Saltwater"), Combination = c("Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Radio", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Satellite", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_PIT", 
"Stationary_Radio", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Stationary_Satellite", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic"), Single_Multiple = c("Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
"Single"), Total_Publications = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -37L), groups = structure(list(
    Size_Groups = c("Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", 
    "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Not Reported", 
    "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
    "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
    "Not Reported", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small"), Depth_Groups = c(">50m", 
    "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", 
    "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
    "Surface-50m", ">50m", ">50m", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
    "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
    "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
    "Surface-50m", ">50m", ">50m", ">50m", ">50m", "Not Reported", 
    "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
    "Surface-50m", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
    "Surface-50m"), Water_Type = c("Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
    "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
    "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
    "Freshwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", 
    "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
    "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
    "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
    "Saltwater", "Brackish", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater"
    ), Combination = c("Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite", 
    "BRUV_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
    "Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Archival", 
    "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
    "Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Radio", 
    "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
    "Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
    "Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Archival", 
    "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
    "Controlled_Satellite", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_PIT", 
    "Stationary_Radio", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
    "Stationary_Satellite", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
    "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
        25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
        36L, 37L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names
```

With all my code together this is what it looks like

```
df |>
  mutate(Combination = fct_reorder(Combination,
                                   ifelse(!Water_Type %in% "Saltwater", 0, Total_Publications),
                                   .fun = sum
  )) |>
ggplot(aes(x = Combination, y = Total_Publications,
    fill = factor(Size_Groups, levels = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Not Reported")))) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, breaks = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Not Reported")) +
  geom_col(width = .5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  # get multiple graphs, ncol puts them in vertical order instead of horizontal
  # and axes, remove labels keeps the x borders for all graphs
  facet_wrap2(~Water_Type, ncol = 1, axes = "all", remove_labels = "all") +
  # increase the text size on x and y axis
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        # change size of axis titles
        axis.title.x = element_text(
          size = 20,
          margin = margin(30, 0, 0, 0)
        ),
        axis.title.y = element_text(
          size = 20,
          margin = margin(0, 30, 0, 0)
        ),
        # increase spacing between facet wrap plots
        panel.spacing = unit(1.5, "lines"),
        # get rid of border around panel
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        # increase text size of table
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        # margin outside of graph, top, right, bottom, left
        plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1.5, 2, "cm")
  ) +
  # change axis titles
  xlab("Method Used") +
  ylab("Total Number of publications")
```

Any idea why it's not working

Comment: Unfortunately your `dput()` is incomplete. But one guess is that your data is grouped, i.e. try with `ungroup()`ing your data before applying `fct_reorder`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues. One problem is passing a grouped dataframe to mutate/ggplot2 (using `ungroup()` is an easy fix). Second is `scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE)` is deprecated, use `scale_fill_viridis_d()` for discrete scale or `scale_fill_viridis_c()` for continuous scale. Third, move `factor(Size_Groups, levels = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Not Reported")))` into your mutate call so your legend title isn't so long.

Do you get your expected outcome if you make these relatively minor changes? E.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

df = structure(list(Size_Groups = c("Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", 
                                    "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Medium", 
                                    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
                                    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Not Reported", 
                                    "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
                                    "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
                                    "Not Reported", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small"), Depth_Groups = c(">50m", 
                                                                                                          "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", 
                                                                                                          "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
                                                                                                          ">50m", ">50m", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Not Reported", 
                                                                                                          "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
                                                                                                          "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", ">50m", 
                                                                                                          ">50m", ">50m", ">50m", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", 
                                                                                                          "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Surface-50m", "Not Reported", 
                                                                                                          "Not Reported", "Not Reported", "Surface-50m"), Water_Type = c("Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Freshwater", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater", "Saltwater", "Brackish", "Freshwater", "Saltwater", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Saltwater"), Combination = c("Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "BRUV_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Archival", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Radio", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Archival", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Controlled_Satellite", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_PIT", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Stationary_Radio", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Stationary_Satellite", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic"), Single_Multiple = c("Single", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Single"), Total_Publications = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -37L))


df |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(Combination = fct_reorder(Combination,
                                   ifelse(!Water_Type %in% "Saltwater", 0, Total_Publications),
                                   .fun = sum
  )) |>
  mutate(Size_Groups = factor(Size_Groups, levels = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Not Reported"))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Combination, y = Total_Publications,
             fill = Size_Groups)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(breaks = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Not Reported")) +
  geom_col(width = .5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  # get multiple graphs, ncol puts them in vertical order instead of horizontal
  # and axes, remove labels keeps the x borders for all graphs
  facet_wrap2(~Water_Type, ncol = 1, axes = "all", remove_labels = "all") +
  # increase the text size on x and y axis
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        # change size of axis titles
        axis.title.x = element_text(
          size = 20,
          margin = margin(30, 0, 0, 0)
        ),
        axis.title.y = element_text(
          size = 20,
          margin = margin(0, 30, 0, 0)
        ),
        # increase spacing between facet wrap plots
        panel.spacing = unit(1.5, "lines"),
        # get rid of border around panel
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        # increase text size of table
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        # margin outside of graph, top, right, bottom, left
        plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1.5, 2, "cm")
  ) +
  # change axis titles
  xlab("Method Used") +
  ylab("Total Number of publications")
```

[image: image2.png]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

(Also, your image dimensions don't lend themselves to the 'default' plotting size, so I've edited my reprex answer with a 'vertically stretched' rendering of the plot)